# max and min of $f(x,y)=e^{x-y}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If I consider the restriction to $x$-axis $f(x,0)=e^x \rightarrow +\infty$ for $x \rightarrow +\infty$ so $\sup f(x,y)$ is $+\infty$.
If $f(x,y)>0$ can I say $\inf f(x,y)$ is zero?

Comment: You also have to show there is no lower bound larger than zero. You can still consider $f(x,0)=e^x$ and take $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: You asked that question already, and deleted it. Since $f>0$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(0,y) = 0$, clearly the infimum is $0$.

Comment: Regarding your title, you realize that $\max,\min$ and $\sup,\inf$ are *different* things, right? There is no $\max$ nor $\min$ for your function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why is it that you write *if* $f(x,y)>0$. If course it is greater than $0$. And, yes, $\inf f(x,y)=0$, since you always have $f(x,y)>0$ and furthermore $\lim_{y\to+\infty}f(x,y)=0$.